# EntityManager always null

Tags: java, spring, ejb, eclipselink, wildfly

I'm using the following configuration:

1. EclipseLink 2.5.2
2. Spring Security 4.0.3
3. Wildfly 9.0.2

And I have a Stateless EJB to execute the basic database operations.

```
@Stateless
public class GenericService {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "VoxFlowPU")
    protected EntityManager em;

    public <T extends DefaultEntity> T save(T entity) {
        if (entity.getId() == null) {
            em.persist(entity);
            return entity;
        } else {
            return em.merge(entity);
        }
    }
    //other methods
}
```

I'm using a custom authentication provider to use Spring Security framework.
I have a UserDao class, and this class needs to execute a basic database operation, and I used @EJB annotation to use the GenericService class.

```
@Repository
public class UserDao {

@EJB
private GenericService genericService;

    public IrisUser loadUserByUsername(final String username) {
        Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("login", username);
        List<IrisUser> users = genericService.findAllBySpecificsParams(IrisUser.class, params);
        if (Utility.isCollectionEmpty(users)) {
            return null;
        } else {
            Role r = new Role();
            r.setName("ROLE_USER");
            List<Role> roles = new ArrayList<>();
            roles.add(r);
            users.get(0).setAuthorities(roles);

            //Caso seja o primeiro login do usuário ele será inserido nas tabelas de relacionamento do sistema
            if (!checkIfUserExistsInVoxFlow(username)) {
                addUserInVoxFlow(users.get(0));
            }

            return users.get(0);
        }
    }
    //other methods
}
```

But when the code reaches the line:

```
List<IrisUser> users = genericService.findAllBySpecificsParams(IrisUser.class, params);
```

the GenericService instance is not null, but the EntityManager is always null. the @PersistenceContext is not instantiating the variable.

Persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="VoxFlowPU" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <jta-data-source>java:/comp/env/jdbc/voxFlowDatasource</jta-data-source>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <class>br.com.voxage.voxflow.entities.Team</class>
        <class>br.com.voxage.voxflow.entities.User</class>
        <class>br.com.voxage.voxflow.entities.Action</class>
        <class>br.com.voxage.voxflow.entities.ActionFields</class>
        <class>br.com.voxage.voxflow.entities.Comment</class>
        <class>br.com.voxage.voxflow.entities.Field</class>
        <class>br.com.voxage.voxflow.entities.FieldType</class>
        <class>br.com.voxage.voxflow.entities.FieldTypeOption</class>
        <class>br.com.voxage.voxflow.entities.Issue</class>
        <class>br.com.voxage.voxflow.entities.IssueFieldsValues</class>
        <class>br.com.voxage.voxflow.entities.Status</class>
        <class>br.com.voxage.voxflow.entities.StatusHistory</class>
        <class>br.com.voxage.voxflow.entities.StatusTeamPermission</class>
        <class>br.com.voxage.voxflow.entities.StatusUserPermission</class>
        <class>br.com.voxage.voxflow.entities.Step</class>
        <class>br.com.voxage.voxflow.entities.Workflow</class>
        <class>br.com.voxage.voxflow.entities.IrisUser</class>
        <class>br.com.voxage.voxflow.entities.IrisTeam</class>
        <class>br.com.voxage.voxflow.entities.FileUpload</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.logger" value="JavaLogger" />
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINE"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.level.sql" value="FINE"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.parameters" value="true"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Wildfly standalone.xml:

```
<datasource jndi-name="java:/comp/env/jdbc/voxFlowDatasource" pool-name="jdbc/voxFlowDatasource" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
    <connection-url>jdbc:sqlserver://MACHINE-NAME;databaseName=voxflow;instanceName=SQLEXPRESS</connection-url>
    <driver>sqlserver</driver>
    <security>
        <user-name>*****</user-name>
        <password>*****</password>
    </security>
</datasource>
```

I already tried a lot of different solutions I had found in foruns, but nothing I did seems to had any effects.

Comment: Can you see some eclipselink logs in Wildfly log? That would mean persistence.xml is detected. Is there any error in that log?

Comment: @LaszloHirdi there is some eclipselink logs like: [org.eclipse.persistence.metadata] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 21) The primary key column name for the mapping element [method getAction] is being defaulted to: nuPkActionId.

Comment: No erros happened.
[org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EjbJndiBindingsDeploymentUnitProcessor] (MSC service thread 1-3) JNDI bindings for session bean named GenericService in deployment unit deployment "VoxFlow-1.0.war" are as follows:

 java:global/VoxFlow-1.0/GenericService!br.com.voxage.voxflow.jpa.GenericService
 java:app/VoxFlow-1.0/GenericService!br.com.voxage.voxflow.jpa.GenericService
 java:module/GenericService!br.com.voxage.voxflow.jpa.GenericService
 java:global/VoxFlow-1.0/GenericService
 java:app/VoxFlow-1.0/GenericService
 java:module/GenericService

Comment: WildFly is a Java EE compliant container. Thus, EJBs you use are governed by the container itself. Spring is completely unaware of them. You need to be explicit to make Spring aware of EJBs. Why don't you instead choose one or the other way i.e. either Spring or Java EE? Things will merely get complecated unnecessarily Usage of Spring does not require a Java EE container either. Many things will be completely unused while using Spring in a Java EE container with several additional Spring dependencies.

Comment: I considered this. Actually I only decided to use Spring Because of the Spring Security technology, so, this class will be the only one to use spring dependencies, the other classes I will use Java EE directly. 
@Tiny

Comment: I only added two spring dependencies in my pom.xml 

`<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency> `

Comment: If the only concerned is using Spring Security in Java EE applications, then Spring Security can also be used to make EJBs secure (using AspectJ) like container managed security but it requires some tricks. Spring Security is an independent module which is not tightly coupled with the Spring framework itself. (One of the concerns with Spring Security to make EJBs secure may be securing remote EJBs. Obtaining the Spring Security context in remote EJBs could be either fishy or tricky which I am not aware of).